# how to do Parallel Computing in dolphindb

Tags: dolphindb

how to do Parallel Computing in dolphindb?

I tested a low capacity table with about one million data. So I create an in-memory table. I want to know can I do Parallel Computing in an in-memory table? Should I save it into a partitioned table?

Answer (score 0):

The function "mr" can help you to implement the parallel computing. For more details, please refer to the [manual](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/m/mr.html?highlight=mr)